# Which free, graphical browser for bibtex can you recommend for Windows 7?

Tags: bibtex

Which free, graphical browser for bibtex can you recommend for Windows 7 (Cygwin is fine, too)?

I have a fairly big bibtex file, which is my entire Cite U like library, and I want to browse it but not by using CUL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mean, like [JabRef](http://jabref.sourceforge.net/)? Thats what I used in my diploma thesis.